# rails + jquery function callback issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

On my page i want to check if the user is logged in and if he is then I allow the user to perform all sorts of operations (such as uploading a photo like below). To check if the user is logged in, I wrote this simple function in jquery..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 function checkLogin(callback){
  <% if !current_user %>
    $.colorbox({href:"/signup", width: "400px", height: "200px"});
    var status = false;
    callback(status)
  <% end %>
 }
```

and when i want to check if a user is logged in or not, I call the above with:

```
$(".upload-pics").click(function(){
  checkLogin(function(c){
    if(c == false){
      return false;
    }
  });
  // open colorbox to upload pictures
  $("a.upload-pics").colorbox();
})
```

The issue is that each time I call checkLogin and say if the user is NOT logged in, the "return false" is not stopping the rest of the code from executing, meaning the colorbox code to upload pictures is fired anyway. The really strange part is that the "return false" does get executed but that does not stop the rest of the code from executing. Do i have some issue with my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because its inside another function..
Do

```
$(".upload-pics").click(function(e){

    var x = checkLogin(function(c){
       if(c == false){
          return false;
       }
    });

    if(!x){
        return false;
    }else{        
       $("a.upload-pics").colorbox();
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't follow. function checkLogin does not return anything so x will always be undefined in your case above. Shall i be changing my function to return some value to satisfy x?

Comment: made a few changes and got to what u were getting at. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, feeling a little silly here. I didn't have to get into callbacks and stuff..here's a very simple way. Thanks to wirey for pointing me in the right direction.

```
function checkLogin(){
  <% if !current_user %>
    $.colorbox({href:"/signup", width: "400px", height: "200px"});
    return false;
  <% end %>
  return true;
}

$(".upload-pics").click(function(){
  var x = checkLogin();
  if(!x){
    return false;
  }
```